# How to keep connection with Spring boot, Hibernate and Websphere Application Server

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, websphere, websphere-liberty

My application uses the frameworks and application server below:

1. Spring Boot(1.5.4.RELEASE) with hibernate.
2. Websphere Application Server Liberty for Java on Bluemix

The application works fine however after the running for hours connections time out. See following exception:

```
2017-09-01T11:40:40.57+0900 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2017-09-01 02:40:40,563 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [5baba2cb-5bfd-4846-b8e0-8782aa729639] [] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [SqlExceptionHelper.java:127] - SQL Error: -4499, SQLState: 08001 
2017-09-01T11:40:40.58+0900 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1).  Message: Connection timed out (Write failed). ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
```

I know Spring boot needs to be set configuration properties in application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000
spring.datasource.numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
spring.datasource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

However, I found out with Spring boot 1.3+, we must use the implementation-specific settings using their respective prefix (spring.datasource.tomcat.*, spring.datasource.hikari.*, and spring.datasource.dbcp2.*), and (apparently) DOES NOT SUPPORT Websphere Application Server Liberty Profile.

My question is **how should I configure to keep connections alive (or renew them)?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The implementation depends on your datasource NOT your application server. Judging from the fact that you have a `spring.datasource` used I assume you aren't using `spring.datasource.jndi-name` and thus you are using one of the supported connections pools. If not, the `spring.datasource` properties (apart from the `jndi-name` one) are pretty much useless as those should be configured in your app server.

Comment: Thank you for your help! As you assumed, I am using `spring.datasource.url` instead of `spring.datasource.jndi-name`. Is there any way to activate `spring.datasource.*` properties when I use `spring.datasource.url` ??? @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0):

What datasource are you using? In our case we are using tomcat which is the default option. So we have

```
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=300000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
```